# Enable two-factor auth in Google Cloud Plaform

Tags: two-factor-authentication, google-cloud-platform

How can I enable Google Authenticator two-factor auth on my Google Cloud Platform account? I've looked up and down "IAM & Admin" in the web interface, but don't see a way to enable 2fa on an account.

Answer (score 5):

I hope this work for you
**Google offers 2-Step Verification** to protect the security of user accounts. This for **Enable two-factor auth in Google Cloud Plaform**

1. **log in** to your Gmail.
2. Goto **Account Settings** page: https://myaccount.google.com/security#signin
   [image]
3. Scroll down to the Signing In section and you will see 2-Step Verification listed as “***Off***.” *Click on 2-Step Verification*., click start setup.
   [image]
4. **Set up your phone number** with Google if you have not already done so. Enter your number and click Send Code.
5. *Enter the verification number Google sends* you in the field provided and click **Verify**.
   [image]
6. If you trust the computer you are using in this setup process, *check the box* labeled “Trust this computer” & click Next.
7. Done!
8. *You should be redirected to here, and you will see that 2-step authentication is ON*.